# Do users have to install Air on their phones to run air app?

Tags: air

I'm going to use adobe air to create an app. Do users have to install air first ? Also can it be bundled within the app itself as just one easy install?

Comment: We distribute an AIR app. I'm not the programmer for it, but I know the users just install it in one step, so it must be bundled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can package app as Captivate Runtime, hence no need to install Air at all.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html

Comment: Is this applicable to mobile phones?

Comment: It's even necessary after Adobe Air 3.6, you can't create APK without Captive Runtime for Android, in case of iOS it was 'captive' already, installing any kind of framework not allowed on by default.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/de/products/air/faq.html#Licensing:

"No, the Adobe AIR free distribution agreement does not allow you to distribute AIR from your website. You must direct visitors to the download center on Adobe.com. To easily link to Adobe.com, we provide Adobe AIR buttons that you can display on your site. If you would prefer not to direct users to Adobe.com, AIR provides a feature called Seamless Install that allows AIR to be installed as part of the application installation process."

Comment: This answer is not really correct. No, you cannot distribute the runtime, but you *can* bundle it using Captive Runtime when compiling. In fact, it is generally recommended that you use Captive Runtime since it forces the user to use the version of AIR you tested with, rather than whatever version they have installed (if they have it installed at all)

Comment: how can the answer not be correct if it's a quotation from the Adobe license agreement? I suspect that what Adobe calls Seamless Install may correspond to your Captive Runtime.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Seamless Install installs the runtime as the user installs the app. It is a separate entity on the machine. Captive Runtime bundles the runtime with your app and it is exclusive to your app. The runtime is part of your app, not just installed on the system. You could bundle AIR 4.0 and the user could have AIR 13.0 installed. Your app will use AIR 4.0 no matter what that user does. This is *exactly* what the OP was asking about. Your quote actually has nothing to do with what was originally asked.